# Elementor Sub menus hidden - z-index Issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index, elementor, jet

Ive been creating a mega menu using Jet Menu with elementor.

I can't for the life of me, figure out a way to get the submenus to appear at the top of the z-index, so they aren't obscured by other elements.

Ive been able to apply a boxshadow to the dropdowns, but trying to apply z-index to that element doesn't do anything.

```
 ul.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -5px #5F5F5F33;
```

}

please view [Site here>>](https://staging-mrsmactivity.kinsta.cloud/), example being the dropdowns within the 'Age 5-7' menu tab.

I can apply 999 z-index to the entire elementor nav menu widget, but that causes other problems with other menus overlapping each other.

Does anyone have any pointers??

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: And apart from that, I can't even tell what exactly is supposedly not working even with the live example. _"example being the dropdowns within the 'Age 5-7' menu tab"_ - you mean those below "Resources & Activities"? Those appear to work fine (on desktop), I can't spot where there'd be any z-index issues ...?

Comment: Hi, see 'Age 5-7' > 'Language & Litterature' > 'Phonics' > dropdown. The drop down overlaps the rest of the content on the container. ?

Comment: Hi No worries, found a workaround, more of a targeting the right elements issue!